# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none) No matching distribution found for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I am using python **Python 3.11.2** and **installed and upgraded pip, pandas, numpy.**
Now I am trying to install matplotlib and seaborn. It's not able to reach URL due to timeout and unable to find the root cause.

**Now my questions are:**

1. Are there any dependencies before installing matplotlib and seaborn?
2. I am performing this activity on company laptop. Is this because of authorization issue?

[image]

```
C:\Users\ABC>pip install matplotlib
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simpleÂ trusted-host=pypi.python.org
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000195D6B81990>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple%C3%82%C2%A0trusted-host=pypi.python.org/matplotlib/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

Upgraded pandas, pip, numpy.
tried with VPN and without VPN
tried office network and home network

Comment: `Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simpleÂ ` looks wrong?

Comment: Yes this was wrong and i updated the pip.ini file with below URL and it starts working. in the file trusted-host=pypi.python.org should be in different line and not same line       [global]

index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple

trusted-host=pypi.python.org